# Spark error "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value need struct type but got decimal(38,18)"

Tags: apache-spark

I have this case class:

```
case class AllData(positionId: Long, warehouse: String, product: String, amount: BigDecimal, amountTime: Long)
```

and dataset:

```
val data: Dataset[AllData]
```

and this code runs fine:

```
 val statisticForAmounts = data.groupByKey(record => record.warehouse + ", " + record.product)
  .agg(
   max($"amount").as("maxAmount").as[DecimalType])
 statisticForAmounts.show(5)
```

but when I do:

```
statisticForAmounts.collect()
```

I get this strange error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from maxAmount#101: need struct type but got decimal(38,18)
```

Here my schema:

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- maxAmount: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
```

What's the cause of the problem and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of the `BigDecimal` incompatibility between spark and Scala. You may want to change it to `Double` and try it.

```
case class AllData(positionId: Long, warehouse: String, product: String, amount: Double, amountTime: Long)

val data1 = AllData(1,"WC","FC",12.11,123)

val data = spark.createDataset(Seq(data1))

val statisticForAmounts = data.groupByKey(record => record.warehouse + ", " + record.product).agg(max($"amount").as("maxAmount").as[Double])

scala> statisticForAmounts.show
+------+---------+                                                              
| value|maxAmount|
+------+---------+
|WC, FC|    12.11|
+------+---------+


scala> statisticForAmounts.collect
res36: Array[(String, Double)] = Array((WC, FC,12.11))
```

Comment: Thanks @Goldie but I have to use BigDecimal and can't switch to Double

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading Spark from 2.1 version to 2.4 version I was able to replace code:

```
val statisticForAmounts = data.groupByKey(record => record.warehouse + ", " + record.product)
  .agg(
   max($"amount").as("maxAmount").as[DecimalType])
```

With:

```
val statisticForAmounts = data.groupByKey(record => record.warehouse + ", " + record.product)
  .agg(
   max($"amount").as("maxAmount").as[BigDecimal])
```

And everything running smoothly. Before upgrade there was no Encoder for BigDecimal